# JSSOR work with iOS5.1.1?

Tags: ios

The captioning slideshow works fine on desktop. When I tried to run it on an iphone 3GS using iOS 5.1.1, it doesn't slide at all. It sticks on the first image with the caption stuck. When I go to your website, and try to run the slideshow demos, every one I try crashes out of safari every time.

Does this only work on newer iOS versions?

Comment: what's your browser version?

Comment: please disable $HWA and have a test.